# Realm downgrade pod to previous version (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

In our project, we have updated Realm pod to 5.0.3 version. We have started observing random crashes in the production app which were not present in Realm version4.3.2. So for a quick fix, we decided to downgrade pod to 4.3.2 again.

After downgrading, Realm giving migration error and getting the following error

**Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B18C551E-DC35-417B-BBA4-123865FEA7A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/8E9F1938-47D2-415F-97C0-BDF933F0E964/Documents/default.realm': Unsupported Realm file format version (10) Path:Exception backtrace:**

We have updated the mirgation ID for Realm configuration but still getting the issue.

We want to downgrade Realm version to 4.3.2 version without reinstlling the app so that production users won't face any issue.

Any help will really appreciated.

Some of the issue reported on realm after version update

1. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6559
2. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6574
3. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6577

Answer (score 1):

As Realm evolves over time, the file format of the `.realm` files periodically change to the point where `.realm` files created with older versions of Realm need to be internally migrated to the new file format specification. This happens automatically when a `Realm` instance is created in code for the first time.

This is different to the `schemaVersion` property in the `Realm.Configuration` object and is an internal implementation detail of Realm that cannot be accessed by external users.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, this file format migration only happens one way. So if a user's `.realm` file has already been upgraded to this new format, but you downgrade the Realm's framework version, the file cannot be migrated back to the old format.

I would highly recommend that you try and resolve the crashes you're having on 5.0.3.

But if you prefer to remain on 4.3.2, the only way to resolve this is to test for that exception, and if it occurs (eg, the user has already had the file upgraded), then to use `FileManager` to physically delete the database file from disk and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your response. We are working on fixing the crashes but it would take time as some crashes are sporadic. So looking to a temporary solution so the user won't affect.

Answer (score 0):

Received response from Realm so closing the issue as downgrading is not possible for v4*.

***Realm files created with version v5.0.0 and above are incompatible with versions less than v5.***